# Style Redux Form 'Field' label

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, redux-form

I need to apply some styling to the label of a Redux Form Field. The Redux Form API doesn't mention any way to style the label. The `classes.formField` class gets applied to the field itself but not the label.

This may also be a question about forcing inheritance because the label, in this case, is not inheriting the parent's styles.

```
import { Field } from 'redux-form'
import TextField from 'redux-form-material-ui/lib/TextField'

  <Field
    className={classes.formField}
    component={TextField}
    label={'style me!!'}
    fullWidth
    name="answer"
    required
    type="text"
    validate={[required]}
  />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add your own `<CustomLabel />` component to the label prop.

```
<Field
    className={classes.formField}
    component={TextField}
    label={<CustomLabel/>}
    fullWidth
    name="answer"
    required
    type="text"
    validate={[required]}

  />
```

Make custom label component and pass it

```
const CustomLabel = () => {
 var labelStyle = {
      color: 'white',
    };
return <label style={labelStyle}> Im the custom label with css </label>
}
```

> In React, inline styles are not specified as a string. Instead they
>   are specified with an object whose key is the camelCased version of
>   the style name, and whose value is the style's value, usually a string.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass props directly to `TextField` using the `props` prop:

```
<Field
  component={TextField}
  props={{ className: classes.formField }}
  label={'style me!!'}
  fullWidth
  name="answer"
  required
  type="text"
  validate={[required]}
/>
```

Sadly this is undocumented on [Redux-Form: Field docs](https://redux-form.com/6.0.0-alpha.4/docs/api/field.md/) :/